# SQL CTE -> Carry a value through from anchor to all rows

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a cte that just cycle throughs a table linking to itself through a child/parent relationship.  I have a seed query and I want to carry a value from the seed query to all it's descendants so that all the rows know which seed it came from.  Any way to do this?

```
WITH   cte
AS     (select Me, MyParent, Attribute 
        from MyTable
        where 
        Attribute in
            (
            847
            ,1011
            ,1019
            )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Link.Me, Link.Parent, Link.Attribute
        FROM   cte
            JOIN LINK ON cte.Me = S.Parent          
       )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH   cte 
AS     (
    select Me, MyParent, Attribute, 'valueToCarry' value_to_Carry
    from MyTable
    where 
    Attribute in
        (
        847
        ,1011
        ,1019
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Link.Me, Link.Parent, Link.Attribute, cte.value_to_carry
    FROM   cte
        JOIN LINK ON cte.Me = S.Parent          
)
```

EDIT after comments:

```
WITH   cte 
AS     (
    select Me, MyParent, Attribute, Attribute RootAttr
    from MyTable
    where 
    Attribute in
        (
        847
        ,1011
        ,1019
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Link.Me, Link.Parent, Link.Attribute, cte.RootAttr
    FROM   cte
        JOIN LINK ON cte.Me = S.Parent          
)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  I need to carry the Attribute Field from the anchor, not a constant value.  You solution works fine for a fixed value.

Comment: the constant was given as an example must be replaced by column you need, as you didn't provide more information. But it seems the query as is can't work because `s` is not defined the clause was `lcte.Me = link.Parent`

Comment: Thanks, I actually had tried this idea after your gave your first one and it did not work, worked today though so I must have did something wrong.

Comment: Maybe you didn't put the same number of column in first and second queries of `union all`, the two parts must have the same number, otherwise in some dbms the columns must be specified after with alias for recursive cte.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a recursive CTE that works on SQL Server.
You basically pass the values from the cte to the second query in the cte.
It's called recursive because the cte calls itself, which makes it loop through all the parents till no parent can be linked anymore.

```sql
-- using a table variable, cos it's a demonstration
declare @MyTable table (Child int, Parent int, Attribute int);

insert into @MyTable (Child, Parent, Attribute) values 
(1,2,847),
(1,3,847),
(2,0,1011),
(3,4,1019),
(4,0,1019);

WITH CTE
AS (
    -- the seed records, where the cte starts
    select 
    Child, Parent, Attribute, 
    Child as RootChild, Attribute as RootAttribute, 0 as PreviousChild, 0 as Level
    from @MyTable
    where Attribute in (847, 1011, 1019)

    union all

    -- the records linked to the previously new records in the CTE
    SELECT 
    link.Child, link.Parent, link.Attribute,
    -- we also take fields from the cte to get the previous data that was put in the resultset of the cte
    cte.RootChild, cte.RootAttribute, cte.Child as PreviousChild, cte.Level + 1 as Level
    FROM cte
    JOIN @MyTable link ON (cte.Parent = link.Child)
)
select * from cte 
order by RootChild, Level;

-- This time we link to the link.Parent which will give different results
WITH CTE
AS (
    select 
    Parent, Child, Attribute, 
    Parent as RootParent, Attribute as RootAttribute, 0 as PreviousParent, 0 as Level
    from @MyTable
    where Attribute in (847, 1011, 1019)

    union all

    SELECT 
    link.Parent, link.Child, link.Attribute,
    cte.RootParent, cte.RootAttribute, cte.Parent as PreviousParent, cte.Level + 1 as Level
    FROM cte
    JOIN @MyTable link ON (cte.Child = link.Parent)
)
select * from cte 
order by RootParent, Level;
```